# How to embed a python interpreter in a django site and secure the server where the code will run?

Tags: python, security, web, embed, interpreter

I tried to do something similar to simply executing the code with `exec()` and `eval()`. In general, the idea worked well, but I understand that it is not enough just to provide the ability to execute code, since someone can execute something harmful to the server (some operating system commands, etc.). I heard that you can use some libraries that limit the set of functions, but as I understand it, this requires some experience. Plus, you need to avoid timeouts when executing code and much more. I would like to hear the opinions of experienced people in this direction, what is better to use and how to implement it without resorting to a deep dive into the work of the Python interpreter?

Here is a code that demonstrates my attempts with `RestrictedPython`.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from RestrictedPython import compile_restricted, safe_globals, safe_builtins
from RestrictedPython import utility_builtins
import sys
import io

def execute_code(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        code = request.POST.get('code', '')
        compiled_code = compile_restricted(code, '<string>', 'exec')
        restricted_globals = dict(utility_builtins)
        restricted_globals.update(safe_builtins)
        restricted_globals['result'] = None

        output_stream = io.StringIO()

        try:
            restricted_globals['_print_'] = lambda *args: output_stream.write(' '.join(map(str, args)) + '\n')
            exec(compiled_code, restricted_globals)
            result = restricted_globals['result']
        except Exception as e:
            result = str(e)

        output = output_stream.getvalue()
        if output:
            result = output.rstrip()

        return render(request, 'result.html', {'result': result})

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

One of the main problems was the output of the result of code execution. I would like it to be immediately displayed in a separate field below the code field. I would like to implement the output through `print()`.

Comment: What's the use case for letting users execute Python?

Comment: I would like to allow simple tasks to be performed, something like `Codewars`. That is, execute the code of only one file.

Comment: If possible, I would recommend running the Python code in the browser using Pyodide instead of the server. That's what I did for my educational Python site https://futurecoder.io/ . You don't have to worry about security or server costs. You can email me for further guidance about that.

Comment: @AlexHall, I understand correctly, all the work is done in the client browser? That is, if the number of users who will simultaneously execute the code is large enough, this will not affect performance?

Comment: Yes, it's the same as when some JavaScript is executed in the browser. The server isn't involved in the code running process.

Comment: @AlexHall, ok, it's good